# Does the Turing test have anything to do with Turing completeness or Turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness, turing-test

I am studying Turing machines and Turing completeness and just remembered I saw something called the Turing test. It seems that the Turing test ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test))

> is a test of a machine's ability to exhibit intelligent behavior
> equivalent to, or indistinguishable from, that of a human.

while Turing completeness and Turing machine are discussed in the context of the theory of computation. Is there a relationship between Turing complete and the Turing test?

I think they are completely separate topics, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: Nice to see I wasn't the only with this confusion

Comment: @HangChen nobody has ever asked it before because you can just google the three things and see what they are. it's also pretty obvious that they're named after the same guy.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, there is no relationship.  The connection is that they are both based on concepts/work by Alan Turing, who was an early pioneer who made many advances.

Comment: Thank you for confirming!

Comment: That should read: "Yes, they were all invented by Alan Turing. But that's about it." ;-)

Comment: It's kinda like how a lot is named after Euler in math.

Comment: Not to stir up anything and this is just me imagining the possibility. But wouldn't it be interesting if somehow, we will learn from some previously unknown source, that Turing actually have an idea how to relate his machine and his test for machine intelligence. Say for example, could it be that he imagined his Universal Turing machine to have on its tape some machine $M$ that will be used to simulate the Turing test and each time $M$ fails, the universal machine alters $M$, until it eventually pass this test.

Comment: @Russel They're only related in the sense that the Turing test is formulated to convince humans that Turing Machines can "think" in the layman sense of the word instead of in the sense of being able to process algorithms or calculate arithmetic results

Comment: @ikegami Inevitable xkcd reference: https://xkcd.com/2721/

Comment: @IMSoP Inevitable xkcd reference: https://xkcd.com/329

Comment: This isn't accurate. For posterity: the Turing test, or imitation game, asks what behaviors a human can demonstrate but a computer cannot; a Turing machine attempts to capture all computable functions in a way which is equivalent to a human calculator in expressive power; and the Turing-complete systems are those which can simulate any Turing machine. Thus, the Turing test asks whether there are behaviors which a human -- but no other Turing-complete system -- can demonstrate.

Answer (score 8):

The relationship exists. All of these were invented by Alan Turing. Alan Turing is the godfather of computer science who laid the solid foundations long before the first electronic computer has even been built. Naming these after him is giving the deserved respect for him, especially since all of these were actually invented by him. His name, again, was Alan Turing.

Answer (score -3):

Negative. They have nothing to do with each other. The Turing test is a tool to assess a machine's ability to display intelligent behavior indistinguishable from that of a human.

There is nothing in the definition saying that the mentioned machine has to be a Turing machine, or that it has to be Turing complete. Nothing, even though any machine implementing an AI algorithm advanced enough to be reasonably expected to pass the Turing test would certainly have to be Turing complete.

All Turing machines are, by definition, Turing complete. All Turing completeness means is the ability to simulate a Turing machine. So, as you see, there isn't any relationship between them at all. Absolutely none whatsoever.

Comment: For the record, this is sarcastic. The acceρted post is bogus and low-effort superficial remark that should have been, at most, a comment.

Comment: I guess being a moderator puts you above the rules and allows you to farm hundreds of points by posting drive-by throwaway stubs and have people vote them up based solely on face value of the moderator badge icon. Sad!

Comment: Imagine a vast lookup table with a response for every possible statement in every possible context. This could pass the Turing test without being Turing complete. Also, not all Turing machines are Turing complete. Turing completeness means being able to simulate _every_ Turing machine.

Comment: In other words, this answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @Draconis No, that table would have to include the answer to "if you run this turing machine on this input, what is the output".  By definition that is Turing-complete.  That is what Turing-complete means - given a description of a Turing machine and its input, be able to tell you the output.  So a machine capable of passing the Turing test as a computer scientist is Turing complete, because humans can (with some paper or equivalent) be a Turing machine.  The point is, Turing-complete is weaker than human-intelligent (up to scale/speed issues, which Turing-complete ignores).

Comment: I did not downvote, but the claim that in order to pass the Turing test, the machine has to be at least Turing complete is not at all that trivial. In fact context-free or context-sensitive grammars are not Turing complete, but can go a long way.

Comment: Sarcastic or not: *reasonably expected* is thin. "The original article" mentions a specific task at which a machine's *success* is compared to that of a human. (It is NOT to pass as a human in a text message exchange, but to tell woman from man in two such exchanges with the communication partners known to be one each.)

Comment: (@Draconis *vast lookup table with a response for every possible statement* isn't finite: not any abstract machine model I'm aware of.)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sure, but then you describe a Turing machine and ask it to run a few billion steps, as one does in a casual conversation, and work out that you are talking to an AI or a non-CS major.